# How to check permissions of a specific directory?

Tags: unix, directory

I know that using `ls -l "directory/directory/filename"` tells me the permissions of a file. How do I do the same on a directory?

I could obviously use `ls -l` on the directory higher in the hierarchy and then just scroll till I find it but it's such a pain. If I use `ls -l` on the actual directory, it gives the permissions/information of the files inside of it, and not of the actual directory.

I tried this in the terminal of both Mac OS X 10.5 and Linux (Ubuntu Gutsy Gibbon), and it's the same result. Is there some sort of flag I should be using?

Answer (score 528):

Here is the short answer:

```
$ ls -ld directory
```

Here's what it does:

```
-d, --directory
    list directory entries instead of contents, and do not dereference symbolic links
```

You might be interested in [*manpages*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manpage). That's where all people in here get their nice answers from.

refer to [*online man pages*](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/)

Comment: I think the man page is poorly worded. I scoured it five times before I started googling. I don't want directory 'entries' (thing 'entered' into directories? Like their files and sub-directories?) nor their 'contents' (they sound like the same concept to me), I want the directories *themselves*.

Comment: it's completely standard terminology, the directories _themselves_ are the directory entries, i.e. entries in the filesystem

Comment: It may be standard terminology, but to someone who would likely be asking such a question, it is probably confusing jargon.

Answer (score 75):

You can also use the `stat` command if you want detailed information on a file/directory. (I precise this as you say you are learning ^^)

Comment: stat will show you amongst a lot of things permissions : (0755/drwxr-xr-x)

Comment: this is handy so you can see the numerical permissions format as well - ty

Comment: "stat -c %a directory" this will show in numerical way

Comment: The corresponding on macOS is `stat -f %A dir_or_filename`.

Answer (score 51):

```
$ ls -ld directory
```

`ls` is the list command.

`-` indicates the beginning of the command options.

`l` asks for a long list which includes the permissions.

`d` indicates that the list should concern the named directory itself; not its contents. If no directory name is given, the list output will pertain to the current directory.

Answer (score 25):

In GNU/Linux, try to use `ls`, `namei`, `getfacl`, `stat`.

### For Dir

```
[flying@lempstacker ~]$ ls -ldh /tmp
drwxrwxrwt. 23 root root 4.0K Nov  8 15:41 /tmp
[flying@lempstacker ~]$ namei -l /tmp
f: /tmp
dr-xr-xr-x root root /
drwxrwxrwt root root tmp
[flying@lempstacker ~]$ getfacl /tmp
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: tmp
# owner: root
# group: root
# flags: --t
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx

[flying@lempstacker ~]$
```

or

```
[flying@lempstacker ~]$ stat -c "%a" /tmp
1777
[flying@lempstacker ~]$ stat -c "%n %a" /tmp
/tmp 1777
[flying@lempstacker ~]$ stat -c "%A" /tmp
drwxrwxrwt
[flying@lempstacker ~]$ stat -c "%n %A" /tmp
/tmp drwxrwxrwt
[flying@lempstacker ~]$
```

---

### For file

```
[flying@lempstacker ~]$ ls -lh /tmp/anaconda.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Nov  8 08:31 /tmp/anaconda.log
[flying@lempstacker ~]$ namei -l /tmp/anaconda.log
f: /tmp/anaconda.log
dr-xr-xr-x root root /
drwxrwxrwt root root tmp
-rw-r--r-- root root anaconda.log
[flying@lempstacker ~]$ getfacl /tmp/anaconda.log
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: tmp/anaconda.log
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
group::r--
other::r--

[flying@lempstacker ~]$
```

or

```
[flying@lempstacker ~]$ stat -c "%a" /tmp/anaconda.log
644
[flying@lempstacker ~]$ stat -c "%n %a" /tmp/anaconda.log
/tmp/anaconda.log 644
[flying@lempstacker ~]$ stat -c "%A" /tmp/anaconda.log
-rw-r--r--
[flying@lempstacker ~]$ stat -c "%n %A" /tmp/anaconda.log
/tmp/anaconda.log -rw-r--r--
[flying@lempstacker ~]$
```

Answer (score 15):

There is also

```
getfacl /directory/directory/
```

which includes ACL

A good introduction on Linux ACL [here](https://serversforhackers.com/video/linux-acls)

Answer (score 10):

This displays files  with its permisions

```
stat -c '%a - %n' directory/*
```

Comment: `stat` is a gnu coreutil that [isn't available on all unix-like systems](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287008/stat-command-not-found) \(such as Solaris < 11\).

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the above posts, i'd like to point out that "man ls" will give you a nice manual about the "ls" ( List " command.

Also, using ls -la myFile   will list & show all the facts about that file.

Answer (score 5):

On OS X you can use:

```
ls -lead
```

The e option shows ACLs.  And ACLs are very important to knowing what the exact permissions on your system are.

Answer (score 2):

ls -lstr

This shows the normal ls view with permissions and user:group as well

Answer (score 0):

To check the permission configuration of a file, use the command:

```
ls –l [file_name]
```

To check the permission configuration of a directory, use the command:

```
ls –l [Directory-name]
```

Comment: this is not the right answer, it should be -ld, as indicated in below anwser

Comment: It's work fine for me . i have set  (assets)  folders permission using these command,

Comment: hmmm... but as the OP has stated: "If I use ls -l on the actual directory, it gives the permissions/information of the files inside of it, and not of the actual directory". I think OP wanted to know the permissions of a FOLDER not the FILES in it.